# Computation of address from Object

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am computing address string form the JS object. I am using EmberJS. I wanted to review my code and tell me how we can improve the computation of address, or is there any better way to it?

```
const {
  get,
  computed,
} = Ember;

// other properties.
completeAdress: computed({
    let address = '';
    if (get(this, 'title')) {
        address = `${address},${get(this, 'title').toString()}`;
    }
    if (get(this, 'number')) {
        address = `${address},${get(this, 'number').toString()}`;
    }
    if (get(this, 'street')) {
        address = `${address},${get(this, 'street').toString()}`;
    }
    if (get(this, 'city')) {
        address = `${address},${get(this, 'city').toString()}`;
    }
    if (get(this, 'region')) {
        address = `${address},${get(this, 'region').toString()}`;
    }
    if (get(this, 'state')) {
        address = `${address},${get(this, 'state').toString()}`;
    }
    if (get(this, 'country')) {
        address = `${address},${get(this, 'country').toString()}`;
    }
    if (get(this, 'zipcode')) {
        address = `${address},${get(this, 'zipcode').toString()}`;
    }
    if (get(this, 'phone')) {
        address = `${address},${get(this, 'phone').toString()}`;
    }
    if (address.length > 0) {
        address = address.substring(1, address.length);
    }
    return address;
}),
// other properties
```

Basically is there any way to avoid too many if conditions.

```
{
  title: 'MacD',
  street: '49'
  // rest of the properties are related to address only
};
// This is example address object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 suggestions..

1. Condense all that duplicated code.
2. Don't concat your strings like that. Every time you do that that string has to be re-loaded into memory all over again. It's more efficient to put your string pieces into an array and then join them later.

> ```
> completeAdress: computed({
>     let address = [];
>     const address_components = ['title', 'number', 'street', 'city', 'region', 'state', 'country', 'zipcode', 'phone'];
>     for(var i=0; i<address_components.length; i++)
>         if (get(this, address_components[i]))
>             address.push(get(this, address_components[i]).toString());
>     address = address.join(',');
>     if (address.length) 
>         address = address.substring(1, address.length);
>     return address;
> }),
> ```

(For some reason the markdown parser didn't want to format this as code unless i also formatted it as a quote.)